# Is there anyone out there using Clear Case with Sybase Powerbuilder?

Tags: version-control, sybase, clearcase, powerbuilder

Word has come from upon high to standardize our SCM system. And upon the clay tablets was written Clear Case.

I am reaching out to anyone who is actually using this configuration - to get best practices, hints and tips, war stories, anything...

The Sybase Source Control newsgroup only gives back the sound of crickets.

We currently have a boatload of actively maintained Powerbuilder 11.5 and EAServer 5.5 systems - so version-ing at the PBL library file level is NOT an option.

And it will be a long, long time before we go to the newest version 12 - which removes the PBL file and uses text files and works as a Visual-Studio plug-in.

Comment: Just curious when you posted to the sybase source control newgroups.  I don't see anything recently posted about Clear Case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always used the following pattern

_work.pbl
_last_minute_changes.pbl
1.pbl
2.pbl
3.pbl
...

I export the objects from 1,2,3... and check them into clearcase.   I set up a nightly build using PowerGen to do a bootstrap import to a network share.  I use a script to pull those pbl's down into my view.  I check an object out of clearcase and import it into my _work.pbl.  Make my changes, export it and check it into clearcase.   A trigger then fires a CI build that imports the object into the _last_minute_changes.pbl and regenerates it against the previous nights pbl's and then archives it to a network share.

I then refresh my view from the share using the script and delete the object from my work.pbl.  When it comes time to deploy we run a script that takes the sync'd pbl's and turns them into pbd's.

I used this process for a team of over 100+ powerbuilder developers in 4 states and it woked really well for us.  Our application had over 12,000 objects and we never had any problems.

Comment: FWIW my answer didn't directly address clearcase as it's not relevant.  However, I'd use snapshot views on the machines building the pbls and dynamic views on the developer machines.  The only time a developer needs to access an object is when they import into work pbl, export and check in.  Dynamic would work well for that.

Answer (score 2):

I do use ClearCase, but not directly with PowerBuilder projects.

The ClearCase manual has:

- an extensive section on [PowerBuilder integration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.int.doc/topics/pb_int/c_overvw_i),
- and a [couple of technotes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctoc&rs=984&uid=swg27010865), including a "
  [Getting started with PowerBuilder and ClearCase Integration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21258623)" document.

The Sybase infocenter (11.5) mentions [settings affecting source controls](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00844_1150/html/pbug/BABCFGFH.htm).

---

PowerBuilder projects or not, I recommend:

- snapshot views for all development activities
- dynamic views for consultation purposes (you can very well have *both*: one dynamic view to test your config spec, and one snapshot view to reuse the same tested config spec and actually copy the files locally)
- CC Vob servers (for hosting the repositories) should be on a LAN. If there are on a WAN, then use CCRC (a RCP client communicating through web with a Web ClearCase Server which, in turn will communicate with the Vob servers on the same LAN)
- CC View servers on a LAN (each client should manage its own view server)

Comment: Thanks. I've read these and until I get a working test environment setup, won't be able to really get the hands on tactile knowledge that I seem to need to understand stuff.  What I guess I was looking for are more process related questions. How frequent do conflicts have to be resolved outside of the IDE? Are the views dynamic or static? are the CC servers located on-site or across a WAN, etc..

Comment: @Rawheiser: I have added some general ClearCase setup recommendations.

Comment: Gracias, The cost part of the equation just went up .. since I think they were expecting a centralized VOB server.  CCRC would require importing/exporting objects and the added opertunities for the pain and error that involves.  That may be fine for the Java code, but not PB.

Comment: To that I'd add, don't even think about using ClearCase over a WAN without replicating to local VOBs. If you're forced into this, use snapshots for everything but the build.

Answer (score 1):

I used ClearCase and PowerBuilder at a previous job.

We were using the IDE-integrated source control, and had it setup so that the individual objects were saved in clearcase as raw text objects (.sro, .srw, etc). I was not the one that exported the objects so unfortunately I can't give details, but I think PB can do at least some of that for you. Anyway, with this configuration when we checked in a file from PB, the IDE would automatically check the .srX file into ClearCase. This is the configuration you need, so that you can view the history of your changes using the ClearCase tools.

We also used PowerGen to automatically create PBL's using the source files in ClearCase. This is also a process you want to set up. Previously to this process we had to manually check the PBL's into source control (!!). I *strongly* advise against you doing this - otherwise you cannot truly guarantee that the .srX files and the PBL's are in sync.

Anyway, that's a brief summary. Let me know if there's anything you would like me to clarify, and I'll do my best. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, 

On one of the very low change PB apps they are only checking in PBLs - since the changes are infrequent, and they just need a record of version deliveries.

Our Build people use PowerGen as well, but its not given to developers.

I am concerned about disk space with both the PBL and SRC files existing on the local disk, and if we have to use UCM that will also balloon the bytes used.

* Did you have each PBL in its own directory?
* How did you bootstrap or provision new developers with source?
* Did you work with any PB object in the Middle Tier?

Comment: (1) Yes, each PBL had its own directory of source files

Comment: (2) PowerGen was integrated into our build process, so if a developer needed a new set of PBL's they would either wait for a build to finish or ask the CM (build) person to kick one off.

Comment: (3) No, this was a desktop application in a client/server environment. But if you have a specific question/concern, perhaps myself or someone else can help...

Answer (score 0):

I am the Source Code Control Administrator and I have been using ClearCase and PowerBuilder together (using the IDE integration) for about 7 years. We have the PBL objects (.srw, .sru, etc) exported and in ClearCase. The PBLs are *not* in ClearCase. We also use PowerGen for regeneration instead of GLV because of GLVs issues with more complex systems.

ClearCase integrates beautifully with PowerBuilder (we are usign 9 and we are doing an ROI on the upgrade to 12).

Search IBM's website for "Getting started with PowerBuilder and ClearCase.pdf". That contains some very good information.